# Tests in Spring-cloud project not getting the configuration correctly when not run in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

**Background**

- Upgrade from Spring-cloud 2021.0.8 to 2022.0.4
- spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap present in the pom

**Before the upgrade**

Following the instructions in [Spring Cloud Kubernetes 2.1.8](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/2.1.8/reference/html/#kubernetes-propertysource-implementations), section [5.1. Using a ConfigMap PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/2.1.8/reference/html/#configmap-propertysource):

> The default behavior is to create a Fabric8ConfigMapPropertySource based on a Kubernetes ConfigMap that has a metadata.name value of either the name of your Spring application (as defined by its spring.application.name property) or a custom name defined within the bootstrap.properties file under the following key: spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.name.

We had a `bootstrap.properties` file under `src/main/resources` like this:

```
# Bootstrap settings for ConfigMap
spring.application.name=${SERVICE_NAME:enterprise-if2nf-if2fe}
#logging.level.org.springframework = debug
```

And then we had its "counterpart" `bootstrap.properties` under `src/test/resources`, like so:

```
# Bootstrap settings to avoid kubernets deployment for test
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enabled=false
```

And with this setup the magic was done: configuration was obtained from the config map when the real microservice was inside a kubernetes cluster but not when component tests started the application context.

**After the upgrade**

After spending some time with the new way of configuring the properties source, as described in the newer version of Spring cloud kubernetes[5.1. Using a ConfigMap PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#configmap-propertysource), the new setup is an `application.properties` file like this, to configure the name of the config map from which the configuration is to be read:

```
spring.config.import=kubernetes:
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.name=${SERVICE_NAME:enterprise-if2nf-if2fe}
```

And, like before, we have a properties file for the profile "test", namely `application-test.yaml`, where we have tried several things without success:

1. Explicitly set `spring.main.cloud-platform: NONE`
2. Do nothing and let defaults do their job
3. Remove the dependency `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` from the pom

The result is always the same:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6c951ada testClass = com.enterprise.if2nf.ct.rest.geode.ControllersDeleteTest, locations = [], classes = [ccom.enterprise.if2nf.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test", "testDalGeode"], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["spring.cloud.bus.enabled=false", "spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=false", "spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.enabled=false", "spring.main.cloud-platform=NONE", "spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true", "org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@67b61834 key = [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.TestChannelBinderConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5a4bef8, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5d8445d7, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@70e659aa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@d816dde, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@e76028b0], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:141) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:97) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:226) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:204) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:142) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$2(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:110) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:110) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:44) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57) [junit5-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) [idea_rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) [junit-rt.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'kubernetes:'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:143) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:128) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:121) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$1(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:102) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:113) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:102) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
```

**QUESTION**

Being my base test class like so:

```java
@ActiveProfiles(value = {"test"})
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = {
      "spring.cloud.bus.enabled=false",
      "spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=false",
      "spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.enabled=false",
      "spring.main.cloud-platform=NONE",
      "spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true"
    })
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MyTestExtension.class, EmbeddedCMRestServerExtension.class})
public abstract class AbstractIf2FeTest {

...

}
```

I have not found in the documentation any way to configure the application, so that integration tests with "test" profile can run outside kubernetes. **Any hint about how this can be configured?**, or where I am missconfiguring something in my current setup?

Thanks a lot.